# Create view for adding new empty model with list property

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Users of my MVC app have the ability to create new "Events". Each "Event" has some properties like name, location, ... Each "Event" also has one or more "Timeframes". When a user wants to create a new "Event", the AddEvent view defaults to 1 timeframe but a user can add extra timeframes. The view looks something like this:

[image: Create view]
<sub>(source: [telenet.be](http://users.telenet.be/evdes/Capture.PNG))</sub>

I can make this work by using a combination of Taghelpers & Jquery.

Model:

```
public class Event
    {
        public Event()
        {
            Timeframes = new List<TimeFrame>();
            Participants = new List<Participant>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Event Name")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage ="The name you've entered is too long")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "The description you've entered is too long")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1,int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage ="Enter a valid number larger than 0")]
        public int WantedAmountOfParticipants { get; set; }


        public List<TimeFrame> Timeframes { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
        public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <partial name="Partials/_EventBasicInputDetails" model="Model" />


    <div id="TimeFramesToAdd">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Timeframes.Count; i++)
        {
                <div class="timeframes" id="Timeframe_@i">
                    <label asp-for="Timeframes[i].EventDate"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Timeframes[i].EventDate" min="@DateTime.Today" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Timeframes[i].EventDate"></span>
                    <label asp-for="Timeframes[i].Starttime"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Timeframes[i].Starttime" min="0" max="24" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Timeframes[i].Starttime"></span>
                    <label asp-for="Timeframes[i].Endtime"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Timeframes[i].Endtime" min="0" max="24" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Timeframes[i].Endtime"></span>
                    <button type="button" class="DeleteTimeframeButton" data-id="@i">Delete Timeframe</button>
                </div>
        }
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="addTimeframe">Add Timeframe</a>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="AllUpcomingEvents">Cancel</a>
        <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
 //Add empty timeframes when adding event
    $("#addTimeframe").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Set counter for dynamical generation of ID attributes for modelbinding
        var i = $(".timeframes").length;

        //Html element to be added
        var newTimeframe = `<div class="timeframes" id="Timeframe_` + i + `">
            <label for= "Timeframes_` + i + `__EventDate" > Event Date</label >
                <input type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Event Date field is required." id="Timeframes_` + i + `__EventDate" name="Timeframes[` + i + `].EventDate" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Timeframes[` + i + `].EventDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                <label for="Timeframes_` + i + `__Starttime">Start</label>
                <input min="0" max="24" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-range="Invalid hour" data-val-range-max="24" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Start field is required." id="Timeframes_` + i + `__Starttime" name="Timeframes[` + i + `].Starttime" value="0" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Timeframes[` + i + `].Starttime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                <label for="Timeframes_` + i + `__Endtime">End</label>
                <input min="0" max="24" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-range="Invalid hour" data-val-range-max="24" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The End field is required." id="Timeframes_` + i + `__Endtime" name="Timeframes[` + i + `].Endtime" value="0" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Timeframes[` + i + `].Endtime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                <button type="button" id="DeleteTimeframeButton_` + i + `" class="DeleteTimeframeButton" data-id=` + i + `>Delete Timeframe</button>
            </div>`

        //Set click event on generated button
        $("#TimeFramesToAdd").append(newTimeframe);
        var button = $("#DeleteTimeframeButton_" + i);
        button.click(removeTimeframe);
    });

    //***Helper Functions***
    function removeTimeframe() {
        if ($(".timeframes").length > 1) {
            var timeframeToRemove = "#Timeframe_" + $(this).data('id');
            $(timeframeToRemove).remove();
        }
    }
```

This works just fine but notice the enormous magic string used to create the HTML element of a new timeframe. This does not seem like the best way to deal with this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use so many magic strings to generate the TimeFrame element with jQuery. The most easy way is to reuse the server side functions to generate the partial forms:

Firstly, create a parital view of `/Views/Shared/_TimeFrames.cshtml`:

```
@model App.Models.Event

@{
    // add a blank one for rendering
    if(Model.Timeframes==null){ 
        Model.Timeframes= new List<TimeFrame>(){}; 
    }
    if(Model.Timeframes.Count==0){ 
        Model.Timeframes.Add(new TimeFrame()); 
    }

    var i = 0;
}

<div class="timeframes">
    <label asp-for= "@Model.Timeframes[i].EventDate" ></label>
    <input asp-for= "@Model.Timeframes[i].EventDate" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" asp-validation-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].EventDate" ></span>

    <label asp-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].Starttime">Start</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].Starttime" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" asp-validation-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].Starttime" ></span>

    <label asp-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].Endtime">End</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].Endtime" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" asp-validation-for="@Model.Timeframes[i].Endtime"></span>

    <button type="button" class="DeleteTimeframeButton" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();return false;"> Delete Timeframe</button>
</div>
```

As you see, we're now able to generate the fields of `TimeFrame` in a strongly-typed way. Names, Ids, DisplayNames and validation rules are generated automatically. You're free to add your own rules.

And now we could render the `TimeFrame` into a client-side template, and reuse  it to generate the `TimeFrame` html elements when someone clicks the "#addTimeframe" button:

```
<script id="timeframe-template-rendered" type="text/plain" >
    @Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_TimeFrames.cshtml",new App.Models.Event()) 
</script>

<!-- a helper that renders the client side template -->
<script>
    function partialFormRenderer(templateStr,index=0){
        var itemTpl = templateStr
            .replace("_"+index+"__","${i}")
            .split(/\$\{(.+?)\}/g);
        return function render(model){
            return itemTpl.map((token,idx)=> idx%2 ===0 ?  token : model[token]).join('');
        };
    }
    // create a render function with the client side template
    var render = partialFormRenderer(document.getElementById("timeframe-template-rendered").innerHTML);
</script>

<script>
    $("#addTimeframe").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var i = $(".timeframes").length;
        var newTimeframe = render(i);
        $("#TimeFramesToAdd").append(newTimeframe);
    });
</script>
```